# weird option of command wc

Tags: command-line, wc

Command wc has an option --files0-from=F. According to the manual, it reads input from the files specified by NUL-terminated names in file F; If F is - then read names from standard input. Why NUL-terminated names? Isn't it more convenient just separating the names with newline or space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's more convenient if you have filenames with spaces (or new-lines, or tabs) in them.

This is sometimes used with `find -print0` that outputs its list of files with `\0` as a separator instead of spaces.

```
$ find . -type f -print0 | wc -c --files0-from=-
15 ./c d
12 ./a b
27 total
```

`xargs` has a `-0` option for similar reasons.